# How to delete a row of a table on checkbox click?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am generating the dynamic table where atlas column I have checkbox I wants to delete the row of the table on click of that checkbox.

I am generating the table dynamically 
Table Structure is 
RolNo|StudentName|Marks|checkbox
Onclick of checkbox I have been creating the another table and copying that selected row so using this..

```
 $('#one tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change',function(e){
  var row=$(this).closest('tr').html();
  $('#two tbody').append('<tr>'+row+'<tr>');
});
```

Now what I want to do is when I click on the second tables checkbox that row should get deleted.

There is another question how can i extract second tables fields in variables if i needed?

Comment: please share your html and code that you have tried so far

Comment: actually i have generated the table from on click of another table and now if i click the checkbox i wants delete that tables row.I don't know how to do it?

Comment: please share your code using jsfiddle link

Comment: I have seen some examples where peoples are deleting the checked rows on button click but i wants this on checkbox click only

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Can you share the html table structure that you are generating dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You need to bind click event to the checkboxes inside dynamically generated table using `.on()` function, see below code

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click","#two input[type='checkbox']",function(){      
     //find the parent tr and remove it
     $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
  });
});
```

**EDIT** - use `.clone()` while copying row from table one to two, so that it will keep seperate copies of each element

```
$('#one tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change',function(e){
  var row=$(this).closest('tr').clone();
  $('#two tbody').append(row);
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro its working.. I am trying to vote u up but i don't have enough reputaions

Comment: There is another question how can i extract second tables fields in variables if i needed?

Comment: fields means input fields?

Comment: fields means table's td

Comment: try this : `$('#two td').each(function(){ alert($(this).html()); });`

Comment: when are you calling this code, you need to call it when there is row in table two

Comment: one more problem is when I am checking the first tables checkbox its checked only and copying the row to other table but when i checked the other table it should get deleted that is working but from parent table it should  get uncheck can you do this?

Comment: here you can use `.clone()`, check edit in my answer.

Comment: what happens over here is when I checks the first table 's check box its copying and second tables check box also also appears checked only.when I uncheck the second table's checkbox it gets deleted but parents tables checkbox is not getting unchecked..

Comment: you copied html of tr from table one and put it in table two. Now both tr having same elements and hence if you bind click event to one checkbox it will get bind to checkbox in both table. Thats why you need to clone the tr from table one and then put it in table two.

Answer (score 1):

if we don't want to show the checkbox in another table we can do this

```
$('#one tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change',function(e){

var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var tempRow = row.clone();
$(tempRow ).find('td:last').remove();
var tds=$(tempRow ).html();
$('#two tbody').append('<tr>'+tds+'</tr>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
$(function(){      
$(document).on("click","table#id input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){      
      $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
      });
});
```

Comment: instead of `.click()` a more appropriate event will be `.change()` instead.

Comment: its not working bro I am generation that second table on click of another table will it work?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#CheckBox').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('tr').remove();

})`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('#CheckBox').click(function(){
       $(this).parents('tr').remove();
   })
})
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.